# How to parse, edit and generate object_detection/pipeline.config files using Google Protobuf

Tags: python, machine-learning, protocol-buffers, config

- I'm training multiple models in a common Ensemble learning paradigm,
  currently I'm working with a few detectors and each time I train I
  have to edit the config file of each detector, this obviously causes
  confusion and a few times I started training with the wrong config
  files.
- As a solution I'm trying to build an editor to the Google Object Detection API
  config files. The config file works with Google [Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).
- Link to the files I use: [pipeline.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/pipeline.proto), [object_detection/protos](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/protos), example [.config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config)

I've tried the following code:

```
from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
with open('/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config', 'rb') as f:
    config = f.read()

read = input_reader_pb2.InputReader().ParseFromString(config)
```

And I get the following error:

```
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-8043e6bb108f>", line 1, in <module>
    input_reader_pb2.InputReader().ParseFromString(txt)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

What am I missing here? what is the appropriate way to Parse and Edit the config file?

Thanks,

Hod

Comment: The .config file is text; GPB's default wireformat is binary. I don't know if there are text wireformats for GPB, but if there are then it might be a case of having to tell the parser what wireformat to expect. Also, the tf_record_input_reader field seems to be defined in input_reader.proto inside a `oneof` called input_reader, so maybe the .config file needs that name (input_reader) in it too. Hopefully this helps set you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the following code I was able to parse a config file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format

from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

def get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override=None):

  '''
  read .config and convert it to proto_buffer_object
  '''

  pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:
    proto_str = f.read()
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  if config_override:
    text_format.Merge(config_override, pipeline_config)
  #print(pipeline_config)
  return pipeline_config


def create_configs_from_pipeline_proto(pipeline_config):
  '''
  Returns the configurations as dictionary
  '''

  configs = {}
  configs["model"] = pipeline_config.model
  configs["train_config"] = pipeline_config.train_config
  configs["train_input_config"] = pipeline_config.train_input_reader
  configs["eval_config"] = pipeline_config.eval_config
  configs["eval_input_configs"] = pipeline_config.eval_input_reader
  # Keeps eval_input_config only for backwards compatibility. All clients should
  # read eval_input_configs instead.
  if configs["eval_input_configs"]:
    configs["eval_input_config"] = configs["eval_input_configs"][0]
  if pipeline_config.HasField("graph_rewriter"):
    configs["graph_rewriter_config"] = pipeline_config.graph_rewriter

  return configs


configs = get_configs_from_pipeline_file('faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config')
config_as_dict = create_configs_from_pipeline_proto(configs)
```

referred from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/c40b46ff63d1af2d32e6457dcb4a70d157648db2/research/object_detection/utils/config_util.py#L79):)

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it now!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `object_detection` API installed, you can just do the following:

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util

pipeline_config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file('/path/to/config/file')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've found to be a useful approach to overriding the object detection pipeline.config:

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection import model_lib_v2

PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH = 'path_to_your_pipeline.config'

# Load the pipeline config as a dictionary
pipeline_config_dict = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH)

# OVERRIDE EXAMPLES
# Example 1: Override the train tfrecord path
pipeline_config_dict['train_input_config'].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = 'your/override/path/to/train.record'
# Example 2: Override the eval tfrecord path
pipeline_config_dict['eval_input_config'].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = 'your/override/path/to/test.record'

# Convert the pipeline dict back to a protobuf object
pipeline_config = config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs(pipeline_config_dict)

# EXAMPLE USAGE:
# Example 1: Run the object detection train loop with your overrides (has to be string representation)
model_lib_v2.train_loop(config_override=str(pipeline_config)
# Example 2: Save the pipeline config to disk
config_util.save_pipeline_config(config, 'path/to/save/new/pipeline.config)
```